# what does cloud hosting "monthly hours of service" mean?

Tags: cloud-hosting

Cloud hosting providers often calculate the cost by hours. When I try to register on RackSpace.Com: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing, there's a field to estimate the monthly cost by average server time. What does this mean? Does it mean if nobody visits my website for an hour, there'll be no cost at all? So the real cost will be much lower, if the website is not yet popular, right?

Thanks

Comment: You should try their FAQ: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/faq/ "There is no "suspension" mode where you are not charged while not receiving traffic to the server."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually means uptime not visited time.

So if it is up all month that is approximately 750 hours of usage.

Comment: which is something I can't control, right?

Comment: I believe they have a dashboard where you can choose to disable your hosting.